# Set panda dataframe index to column name when column name is not unique

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have two tables of stock tickers.

I create SQL joined query to combine the two tables.

```
query_combined = session\
.query(Table1, Table2)\
.join(Table2, Table1.ticker==Table2.ticker)
```

I then feed the SQL to Pandas to load in a frame:

```
df_combined = pandas\
    .read_sql(query_combined.statement, 
              query_combined.session.bind, 
              index_col='ticker')
```

However, since there are two "tickers" columns from the joined tables, setting the index_col='ticker' results in a tuple for the index column of '(ticker, ticker)'.   **I just want to specify one of the "ticker" columns as the dataframe index but am unsure how.**

I am new to pandas and am sure this is very simple, but in my hour of Googling, I haven't found the answer.  Many thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`with_labels`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_labels) to qualify ambiguous columns with underscores `<table>_<column>`:

```
df_combined = (pandas
                 .read_sql(query_combined.with_labels().statement, 
                           query_combined.session.bind, 
                           index_col='Table1_ticker')
              )
```

To shorten table name, [alias](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=aliased#sqlalchemy.orm.util.AliasedClass) the tables before the join:

```
t1 = aliased(t1, Table1)
t2 = aliased(t2, Table2)

query_combined = (session
                    .query(t1, t2)
                    .join(t2, t1.ticker==t2.ticker)
                  )
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works like a charm.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Happy coding!